# Need To Pull Most Recent Record By Timestamp Per Unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group

I'm going to apologize up front, this is my first question on stackoverflow...

I am attempting to query a table of records where each row has a VehicleID, latitude, longitude, timestamp and various other fields.  What I need is to only pull the most recent latitude and longitude for each VehicleID.

edit: removed the term unique ID as apparently I was using it incorrectly.

Comment: What database are you using?  When posting a question, it is a good idea to tag the question with the database.

Comment: If each row has an unique id, then the recent_date (and any other field) will be functionally dependant on that id, and there will be no way to aggregate the data. What field(s) do you want to aggregate on? *not* the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Unique ID is truely unique, then you will always have the most recent latitude and longitude, because the ID will change with every singe row.

If the Unique ID is a Foreign Key (or an ID referencing a unique ID from a different table) you should do something like this:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, unique_id
FROM table INNER JOIN
(SELECT unique_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM table
GROUP BY unique_id)t2 ON table.timestamp = t2.timestamp
AND table.unique_id = t2.unique_id;
```

Comment: I tried the following:   `SELECT Latitude, Longitude, VehicleKey
FROM AVLVehiclePosition INNER JOIN
(SELECT VehicleKey, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM AVLVehiclePosition
GROUP BY VehicleKey)t2 ON AVLVehiclePosition.timestamp = t2.timestamp
AND AVLVehiclePosition.VehicleKey = t2.VehicleKey;`

And it returned "Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'VehicleKey'

Comment: @poisedforflight There is unqualified `VehicleKey` in select list. Qualify it: `AVLVehiclePosition.VehicleKey`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `row_number()` function for this purpose:

```
select id, latitude, longitude, timestamp, . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential value to each id (`partition by` clause), with the most recent time stamp getting the value of `1` (the `order by` clause).  The outer `where` just chooses this one value.

This is an example of a `window` function, which I encourage you to learn more about.

One quibble with your question:  you describe the id as unique.  However, if there are multiple values at different times, then it is not unique.

Comment: I'm probably using the term incorrectly, but the VehicleKey is always the VehicleKey for said vehicle.  There are probably 100 vehicles in the table.

Comment: @poisedforflight . . . Based on your question, the `id` (or whatever you call it) is not unique . . . which is the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to implement row indexes and utilize the partition to reset per group. Then in your WHERE clause filter out the results that aren't the first.