# MySQL Max statement not returning result

Tags: mysql, database, max

I have the following MySQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM user_messages AS T WHERE user_id = '33' AND id = (SELECT Max(id) from user_messages AS TT WHERE T.from_userid = TT.from_userid) ORDER BY status, id DESC
```

The problem I seem to be having is when I only have one record.  I would think that MySQL would return the single record associated with user_link = '33', but instead it returns nothing.

I need to use the "Max" function because I use it to pull the most recent entries.  I am trying to avoid having multiple queries or having to use php to sort also.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Gordon, I checked the database, and the record exists.  I did some more research, and what it turns out to be is that I needed to join the data.  I was able to return the Min or Max record, but the corresponding/related fields weren't returned with it.

`SELECT * FROM user_messages INNER JOIN(SELECT from_username, MAX(id) AS id FROM user_messages WHERE user_link = '33' GROUP BY from_username ORDER BY status, id DESC) t2 ON user_messages.id = t2.id AND user_messages.from_username = t2.from_username`

The thread that answered the question was this one - [Need To Pull Most Recent Record By Timestamp Per Unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326481/need-to-pull-most-recent-record-by-timestamp-per-unique-id)

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_messages AS T
WHERE user_id = '33' AND
      id = (SELECT Max(id)
            from user_messages AS TT
            WHERE T.from_userid = TT.from_userid
           )
ORDER BY status, id DESC
```

Here are three reasons it could be failing to return any rows.  First, `user_id = '33'` may not exist in the table.  Second `from_userid` may be NULL.  Third, the `id` value may be NULL for all matching records.

Perhaps this simpler version would help:

```
select *
from user_messages um
where user_id = '33'
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I went over the three reasons you gave for it failing, and none of those are true unfortunately.  The basic idea is that I have a field "from_userid", and I am trying to pull the latest message associated with the "from_userid" field, by pulling the max(id), which should return a from_userid & id result, or in other words, pull the latest record per userid.  I thought I had it using the group statement, but no luck yet :(